# NHibernate One-To-Many Delete Not Cascading

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, relational-database, cascading-deletes, nhibernate-cascade

I have a 'Photo' class and a 'Comment' class. An Photo can have multiple comments assigned to it.

I have this configured as a one-to-many relationship within my HBM mapping file, and have set cascade="all-delete-orphan" against the 'Comments' bag within the Photo.hbm.xml mapping file.

However, if I try to delete a Photo which has 1 or more Comments associated with it, I am getting 'The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Comments_Photos"'

I tried a couple of other cascade options against the Comments bag in my Photo.hbm.xml but regardless of what I set it to, I'm getting the same outcome each time. I just want to be able to delete a Photo and have any associated comments automatically delete too.

Here is my Photo mapping (edited for brevity):

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" .... default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Photo" table="Photos">
    <id name="PhotoId" unsaved-value="0">
        <column  name="PhotoId" />
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    ...
    <bag name="Comments" table="Comments" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="DateTimePosted desc" where="Approved=1">
        <key column="PhotoId" />
        <one-to-many class="Comment" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

Here is my Comment mapping (edited for brevity):

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" ... default-access="property" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
<class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="Comment" table="Comments">
    <id name="CommentId" unsaved-value="0">
        <column name="CommentId"></column>
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    ...
    <property name="Author" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Body" not-null="true" />
    <property name="Approved" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Photo" not-null="true">
        <column name="PhotoId" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the cascade is not happening when I try to delete a Photo with comments associated with it?

**UPDATE:** The only way I can get the cascade to happen is to configure the 'Delete Rule' within SQL Server against this relationship to 'Cascade', and in doing so means that I don't need to specify any cascade action within my NHibernate Mapping. However, this isn't ideal for me - I'd like to be able to configure the cascade behaviour within the NHibernate Mapping ideally, so I'm still confused as to why it doesn't appear to be taking any notice of my NHibernate cascade setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be that the problem comes from the fact that the many-to-one in the Comment mapping is set to not-null="true".
Because of that, NHibernate is not allowed to set this property to null temporarily before it deletes the Photo object and therefore when is goes about deleting the Photo object SQL Server throws an foreign key exception.

If I remember correctly for the order of actions when deleting is:

1. Set foreign key value to null in all child objects
2. Delete parent object
3. Delete all child references

Try to remove the not-null="true" from the many-to-one and see what will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this but still the same problem/error message. If I remove the existing relationship/Constraint within SQL Server, then the Deletion of the Photo record takes place without any errors, but leaves my orphaned related Comment record in the DB. It's like it's only taking notice of how things are configured within SQL Server, and ignoring any cascade settings outside of SQL Server.

Comment: You definitely need to remove not-null="true" then add the inverse="true" that Felice suggested and it is really needed anyway, and finally leave the cascade="all-delete-orphan". I wouldn't mess with SQL server as what you do there is irrelevant with what NHibernate needs to do. Yes, if add cascade delete in SQL server can help but this is a problem that can be solved entirely with properly configuring the entity mapping files. So if I were you I would remove the SQL constraint from the server and try again with the above recommendations for the mapping files.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info tolism7. OK, I've removed all SQL Server constraints, removed not-null="true" from the many-to-one and added inverse="true" on the bag, but when I delete a Photo, it's still leaving orphaned Comments in the DB :(

Comment: I wonder if it only leaves back comments that they do not satisfy the where="Approved=1" clause. Have you tried removing this one to see how it goes? Better yet have you used SQL Profiler or NHProf to see if a delete statement is fired for comments?

Comment: Aha! Removing the WHERE clause has indeed sorted it! The comment record(s) now get removed automatically. Thanks! At least I now understand where it was going wrong. Now I guess I need to figure out how to get around the WHERE clause side of things.

Comment: not-null="true" shouldn't actually influence the runtime behavior of NH. AFAIK, it is only used for schema creation.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `inverse="true"` on the bag collection of your mapping.

Comment: I did also try that (when nothing else was working), but with no success unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem for 1 day .. and got frustrated over it.

Finally the solution boiled down to the DB.
I had to change the FK key constraints in "INSERT UPDATE SPECIFICATION"
'Delete Rule' : from 'No Action' to 'Cascade'

additionally you can also set
'Update Rule' : from 'No Action' to 'Cascade'

Answer (score 1):

You *can* specify the delete-cascade option in NH:

```
<bag name="Comments" cascade="all-delete-orphan" order-by="DateTimePosted desc" where="Approved=1">
    <key column="PhotoId" on-delete="cascade"/>
    <one-to-many class="Comment" />
</bag>
```

You probably should make it inverse. Then I wonder where your FK_Comments_Photos column is specified.